# Output caching _ViewStart.cshtml and _Layout.cshtml in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, master-pages, outputcache

I am trying to cache the MVC 3 _ViewStart and _Layout pages, am I right in thinking these are not cached by default? The problem is the VS bult in web server or IIS should be caching my images in these site master pages but it seems to be loading them everytime.

I can put OutputCache attributes on controller but I can't on these pages above as they have no controllers. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

`_ViewStart` and `_Layout` are only composing elements of the final markup. So by using the `[OutputCache]` attribute on some controller action you are caching the entire generated HTML from this action, including the view, and you are in fact caching those elements as well.

Unfortunately ASP.NET MVC 3 doesn't support [Donut Caching](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/05/donut-caching-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx). It supports only [Donut Hole Caching](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/05/12/donut-hole-caching.aspx). I guess this is something that is going to be improved and added support to in future versions.

Comment: Thanks Darin, what if all my content inside these pages is static and I just want to cache it all?

Comment: @David, simply decorate some controller action with the OutputCache attribute and the contents will be cached.

Comment: But I;ll have to do this on all controllers, can't I just do it centrally?

Comment: @David, unfortunately ASP.NET MVC 3 doesn't support [Donut Caching](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/05/donut-caching-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx). It supports only [Donut Hole Caching](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/05/12/donut-hole-caching.aspx). I guess this is something that is going to be improved and added support to in future versions.

Comment: @Darin, so by default if I ust enable OutputCache on Home/Index and it includes the entire HTML: someone visits /Home/ and the Layout contains the _LogOnPartial in a default MVC app which displays one user's name, would that be cached by default for all users?  I.e. Bob would see "Aaron" if I had been there first?

Comment: @AaronLS, yes, it will be cached for all users.

Comment: For anyone else stumbling on this, I've found this to be a good solution: http://mvcdonutcaching.codeplex.com/